# Как правильно написать: "В Назарово или в Назарове"?

Tags: склонение

Назарово - это город.

Answer (score 2):

Топонимы славянского происхождения, оканчивающиеся на *-ово,* не склоняются в сочетании с родовым словом: *в городе Назарово.* Если же родового слова нет, то нормативны оба варианта, склоняемый и несклоняемый: *в Назарове и в Назарово.* При этом склоняемый вариант соответствует строгой литературной норме (и рекомендуется, например, для речи дикторов). См. об этом заметку канд. филол. наук В.М. Пахомова: [тынц.](http://www.gramota.ru/class/istiny/istiny_1_toponimy/)